# Tor is making me an exit node despite configuration?

Tags: configuration, relays, nyx

I am trying to create a non-exit relay. I have edited the `torrc` file to `ExitPolicy reject *:*`, but when I monitor my connection in `arm` it lists my relay nickname as an "EXIT" in multiple circuits. Is this what I think it is? Am I an exit despite having explicitly configured the file otherwise? Because it was really disappointing to see how my request was breached so easily, I cannot afford this type of error.

This happens even when I allow arm to configure the `torrc` for me and I ask it to be an internal relay only. What is causing this, how do I stop it? Man, I've had to jump through so many hoops trying to get this thing going...

Comment: Did you tried with the setup provided by arm?

Comment: don't worry, it's a bug/misunderstanding in ARM itself

Answer (score 1):

I asked that March '14 in another [post](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/tor-relay-acts-as-an-exit-with-reject).

ARM don't differentiates between internal and external (to the normal web) circuits. Your relay is probably correct configured and will not relay as an Exit to the normal web.

2 tickets exist to clarify that UX problem in ARM.

Ticket: [6430](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/6430)

> Perhaps internal circuits which are not for directory fetches could simply be called "END" hops or "FINAL" hops? Rather than suggesting that anything is actually exiting the network, which seems to be the particular bit of terminology that is frightening folks.

Ticket: [12956](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/12956)

> I think for non-general-purpose circuits, we should call that third hop something else. I'm open to suggestions -- one option would be to just call the last hop on a non-exit circuit "Middle" also. Another option would be to call it "Internal".